# COBOL subroutine that reads a file and can be called online or in batch

Tags: cobol, cics

To all my VSE Mainframe programmers:

I am working on a VSE mainframe system and I am trying to build a subroutine that needs to read a file but must also be able to be called by both online and batch programs.

To be more specific about the subroutine and how I need to access the file:

I need to be able to pass a key value to the file and then be able to view the data for that key should it exist on the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought of anything? Please post that as well.

Comment: There was one method that I thought of but I'm not entirely sure if it is possible.  In the past, I glimpsed at using fetchables to access databases across batch and online programs and I thought that that process would be able to be applied here.  That, however, was at a previous job and I can't recall exactly how they are setup or if it is even possible on a VSE system.

Comment: How are you going to "view" the file from a batch program?

Comment: Sorry, "view" was a bad word choice.  I was implying that the program would view the data not the user.  "Access" would probably have been a better word.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is to have a separate program that is CALLed to handle the batch file IO and one that will do file IO via CICS API calls.  At runtime, have your subroutine decide which environment it is in and invoke the correct IO program for the environment, and then do all your common calculations.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to figure out a way similar to that but was stuck at how to do it.

Comment: Perhaps a useful link to add: http://enterprisesystemsmedia.com/article/common-cobol-vse-applications-for-use-in-cics-and-batch-environments#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1404800082

Answer (score 0):

CICS has a piece that can be installed called EXCI (External CICS Interface) which will allow a batch program to call an online program sharing the commarea. Might have the online program read the file all the time and call it from batch or else where.

Pdf ref link: 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v4r2/topic/com.ibm.cics.ts.doc/dfhtm_pdf.pdf